# How to remove drop shadow of Java AWT Frame on OSX?

Tags: java, macos, awt, frame, dropshadow

Is it possible to disable the drop shadow of a Java AWT application on OS X?
I want to create a transparent window, which works fine, but I cannot get rid of the drop shadow.

If I was using a `JFrame` this could be done using:

```
 JRootPane root = frame.getRootPane();
 root.putClientProperty( "Window.shadow", Boolean.FALSE );
```

Any similar possibility for an AWT Frame?

I' using the Framework [Processing](http://processing.org/) and my code there looks like this:

```
void setup(){
  frame.removeNotify();
  frame.setUndecorated(true);
}
```

Processing itself does the main Frame creation, here is the [source](http://code.google.com/p/processing/source/browse/trunk/processing/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java).

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple application that uses a transparent window running on Max OS X 10.7.5 under Java 7 (has run under Java 6) which has no problems...

[image]

Share some code so we can replicate the issue

**Updated from feedback**

I have tested this on Mac OS 10.7.5 & 10.8.2, using JDK 1.7.0_07 & 1.6.0_37

Without and with `Window.shadow` property...

[image][image]

Without going into a lot of tests and without further information, I would suggest you want to make this call as early as you can.  If that doesn't work, make it the last call before you make the window visible.

This may be related to how Java/AWT connects to it's native peer, presumably, once the connection is made, you will no longer be able to effect these kinds of properties...

```
public class TransparentFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TransparentFrame();
    }

    public TransparentFrame() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
                // Use this to test the transparentancy API
                //doTransparentFrame();
                doDropShadow();
            }

        });
    }

    protected void doDropShadow() {
        String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
        System.out.println(version);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        JRootPane root = frame.getRootPane();
        root.putClientProperty("Window.shadow", root);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setContentPane(new ContentPane());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new ImagePane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void doTransparentFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setContentPane(new ContentPane());

        String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
        System.out.println(version);
        if (version.startsWith("1.7")) {
            frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        } else if (version.startsWith("1.6")) {
            if (supportsPerAlphaPixel()) {
                setOpaque(frame, false);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Per Pixel Alphering is not support with Java " + version);
                System.exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Per Pixel Alphering is not support with Java " + version);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new ImagePane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static boolean supportsPerAlphaPixel() {

        boolean support = false;

        try {

            Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
            support = true;

        } catch (Exception exp) {
        }

        return support;

    }

    public static void setOpaque(Window window, boolean opaque) {

        try {

            Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
            if (awtUtilsClass != null) {

                Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpaque", Window.class, boolean.class);
                method.invoke(null, window, opaque);

            }

        } catch (Exception exp) {
        }

    }

    public class ContentPane extends JPanel {

        public ContentPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        }

    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;
        private BufferedImage offImage;
        private Ellipse2D offButton;
        private boolean mouseIn;

        public ImagePane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("tamagotchi400.png"));
                offImage = ImageIO.read(new File("powerSmall.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            offButton = new Ellipse2D.Float(212, 330, 25, 25);
            MouseAdapter handler = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 1 && e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                        if (offButton.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                            Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(ImagePane.this);
                            if (window != null) {
                                window.dispose();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    Cursor cursor = Cursor.getDefaultCursor();
                    if (offButton.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                        cursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
                    }
                    setCursor(cursor);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    mouseIn = true;
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    mouseIn = false;
                    repaint();
                }

            };
            addMouseListener(handler);
            addMouseMotionListener(handler);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? new Dimension(400, 400) : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
                if (mouseIn && offImage != null) {
                    g2d.drawImage(offImage, (int) offButton.getX(), (int) offButton.getY(), this);
                }
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The code also includes transparency test code to test the transparency API now available in Java 1.7 and Java 1.6_10+.  I've used this code successfully in a number of projects, its less cumbersome then the AWT Robot "hack" and provides a live back ground, but that's a choice you need to make.

**Updated**

Demonstration using `java.awt.Frame`

[image]

```
public class TestTransparentFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTransparentFrame();
    }

    public TestTransparentFrame() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                }

                Frame frame = new Frame("Test");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                setOpaque(frame, false);
                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }

                });
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ContentPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class ContentPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;

        public ContentPane() {
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("duke.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            setOpaque(false);
            JButton close = new JButton("Close");
            close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(ContentPane.this).dispose();
                }
            });
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(close);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background != null) {
                g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
            }
        }

    }

    public static boolean supportsPerAlphaPixel() {

        boolean support = false;
        String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
        if (version.startsWith("1.6")) {
            try {
                Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
                support = true;
            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
        } else if (version.startsWith("1.7")) {
            try {
                Class<?> winTransClass = Class.forName("java.awt.GraphicsDevice$WindowTranslucency");
                Field field = winTransClass.getField("TRANSLUCENT");

                GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

                gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency.TRANSLUCENT);

                Method isWindowTranslucencySupported = GraphicsDevice.class.getMethod("isWindowTranslucencySupported", winTransClass);
                System.out.println(isWindowTranslucencySupported);

                Object value = isWindowTranslucencySupported.invoke(gd, field.get(null));
                if (value instanceof Boolean) {
                    support = ((Boolean) value).booleanValue();
                }

            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
        }
        return support;
    }

    public static void setOpaque(Window window, boolean opaque) {

        String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
        if (version.startsWith("1.6")) {
            try {
                Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
                if (awtUtilsClass != null) {
                    Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpaque", Window.class, boolean.class);
                    method.invoke(null, window, opaque);
                }
            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
        } else if (version.startsWith("1.7")) {
            Color color = UIManager.getColor("Panel.background");
            if (opaque) {
                color = new Color(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue());
            } else {
                color = new Color(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), 0);
            }
            window.setBackground(color);
        }

    }

}
```

Tested on Windows 7 Java 1.6 & 1.7, Mac OS 10.7.5 & 10.8.2, using JDK 1.7.0_07 & 1.6.0_37

It appears that you don't understand the window hierarchy in Java

All "windows" in Java derive from `java.awt.Window`.

`JFrame` extends `Frame` which extends `Window`.

Comment: There is no issue, I just don't know how to get rid of the drop shadow in a blanc AWT frame.

Comment: I use transparent frames on the Mac OS without a lot, they do not display the drop shadow. Can you share some code so we can see how you are creating your window and so we can replicate it, that way we might be able to help some more

Comment: So you're sample code isn't going to make a transparent frame, but a framless one

Comment: Yes, I'm displaying a screenshot of the desktop, which looks like it's transparent. There are also functions to create a transparent frame using AWTUtilities, but these functions are windows only. Using the screenshot-method, creating a "transparent" frame is working for me... except the shadow.

Comment: Ahhh...now where getting some where ;)

Comment: *"but these functions are windows only"* - If you mean MS Windows, then there not, they work fine on the Mac OS.  If you mean `java.awt.Window`, then yes, but `JFrame` extends from `java.awt.Window` ;)

Comment: Yes but you are talking about a JFrame here, the functionality is needed for a Frame (no Swing).

Comment: Okay, fair point, missed that...however, Java 6's `AWTUtilities#setWindowOpacity` method accepts a `Window` which `Frame` extends from.  From that perspective you can achieve a transparent frame without needing to resort to the `Robot` hack. I will need to test the background color.

Comment: I'm still testing, but under Java 7 & Java 6 under Windows I can make a `Frame` transparent. I will need to test it on my Macs's when I get home

Comment: Now tested and demonstrated using a `java.awt.Frame`

Answer (score 0):

Using this line, it works:

```
AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(frame, false);
```

Eclipse prints out a warning on this and I had to change some settings to comile it, so I guess there may be better ways.
I read [here](http://www.visualinformation.org/2009/09/transparent-application-window-in-processing/), that this is supported since OS X 10.6 (Lion).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when your frame is not focus, the shadow effect will be triggered. Try adding this code so your frame will disabled being focus.

```
frame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a shadow problem with JInternalFrame on OSX today, and I found this solution for another forum (verified on Java 11, Catalina 10.15)

```
internalFrame.putClientProperty("JInternalFrame.frameType", "normal");
```