# How to make a JFrame Transparent?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, applet, transparency

I have been working on a screen recorder app in Java.

I need to know ho to create a JFrame fully transparent?

Like this.

[image]

Comment: Caveat - I believe you can't do this with a decorated window, but take a look at [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844927/java-transparent-window/11853691#11853691) using both Java 6 and Java 7 and [an example with components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546644/how-to-remove-drop-shadow-of-java-awt-frame-on-osx/13547998#13547998)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a JFrame partially transparent using the [`frame.setOpacity(float opacity)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setOpacity-float-) method.

For more information, see [the Java Tutorial on the subject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html).

**Caution:** If you make if the frame 100% transparent, users won't be able to see it.